# SQL Server : CAST within EXEC (Dynamic SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to dynamically compute a column name, however SQL Server doesn't let this happen. Is there a correct way of doing this?

Expected result

```
SELECT Column_1
FROM Table
```

Query

```
DECLARE @param AS INT;
SELECT @param = 1;

EXEC('SELECT Column_' + CAST(@param AS VARCHAR) + ' FROM Table');
```

Catch: the `@Param` needs to be int, for convenience of providing input.

Comment: This is a sign that your table is violating 1NF with what is known as repeating groups. This is a horrible way to model data and causes all sorts of problems. And if you are going to use varchar you MUST specify the size. If you don't is uses a default. The default for a parameter is 1, but for a variable it is 30. Be explicit and avoid confusion or errors.

Comment: Ah, I totally get your point @SeanLange! And true, this might just violate one or all of the Normal Forms. However, just as a background this is not for an OLTP system - but one-off analysis on a known and limited set of data.

Comment: Doesn't matter what the usage is, the design is the problem. When you see things like Email_1, Email_2, Email_3 it is a sign that everything is going to be an uphill battle. If you design tables correctly it is simple to retrieve data from them. And sadly you struggling to retrieve data...

Comment: True, I'm the analyst stuck with the bad design.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please use like this

```
DECLARE @param AS INT;
SELECT @param=1;
DECLARE @SQL AS VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT Column_'+CAST(@param AS VARCHAR(5))+' FROM Table'
EXEC(@SQL);
```

Comment: If you specify the size of the varchar inside the cast this is a good way to handle a bad design.

Comment: I have updated the size to varchar(5). :) Thanks Sean.

Answer (score 1):

> you do not need to use a numeric variable if you are not doing an
>   arithmetic operation.

`DECLARE @param VARCHAR`

```
DECLARE @param VARCHAR
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @param = '1';
SET @sql = 'select ' + 'Column_' + @param + ' From Table';
EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use