# Select Query Parameter from C# in a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, stored-procedures

How does a SQL Server query select from parameter? I just want to make it simple set select column based on my C# code. Is it possible?

Here is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetMembersDetailGenerateChanceTop10000]
    @EventId nvarchar(255), 
    @PeriodId nvarchar(255), 
    @QueryParam nvarchar(1000)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10000 @QueryParam
    FROM ign..Chance_Generated cg
    INNER JOIN ign..Contact c ON cg.ContactID = c.ContactId
    LEFT JOIN ign..CustomerAddress ca ON ca.parentid = cg.contactid 
    LEFT JOIN ign..new_cardlevelconfig cl ON cl.new_cardlevelconfigid = c.new_cardlevel
    LEFT JOIN ign..new_country co ON co.new_countryid = c.new_country 
    LEFT JOIN ign..new_province po ON po.new_provinceId = c.new_Province
    LEFT JOIN ign..StringMap sm ON sm.AttributeValue = c.new_IDType
    LEFT JOIN ign..new_city cy ON cy.new_cityId = c.new_CityCounty
    LEFT JOIN ign..new_transactionheader th ON cg.New_Name COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = th.new_name COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
    WHERE cg.EventId = @EventId 
      AND (ca.AddressNumber = '1' OR ca.AddressNumber IS NULL) 
      AND (sm.AttributeName IS NULL OR sm.AttributeName = 'new_idtype') 
      AND cg.periodId = @PeriodId
```

`QueryParam`, `EventId`, `PeriodId` will be filled from C# code.

Here is my C# code:

```
private List<GenerateModel> getDataTopFromStoreProcedure(string EventId, string PeriodId)
{
    // query select parameter
    string QueryParam = @"cg.Chance_Number, th.new_name as [th name], dateadd(HOUR,7,th.createdon)  as [th createdon], 
                        c.new_Initial, c.FirstName, c.LastName";

    string ConnString = GenerateChance.Properties.Settings.Default["DB_ConnectionString"].ToString();

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = GetMembersDetailGenerateChanceTop10000;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 0; //no limit

        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("QueryParam", QueryParam));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("EventId", EventId));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("PeriodId", PeriodId));

        cmd.Connection = conn;

        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            conn.Close();

        conn.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                list.Add(new GenerateModel
                {
                    ChanceNumber = reader["Chance_Number"].ToString(), //System.IndexOutOfRangeException Error
                    Receipt = reader["th name"].ToString(),
                    Date = reader["th createdon"].ToString(),
                    Initial = reader["new_Initial"].ToString(),
                    FirstName = reader["FirstName"].ToString(),
                    LastName = reader["LastName"].ToString(),
                });
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

I am confused as to how to implement his method because I want to get return of all select results in object model but I always get error

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException : Chance_Number.

Honestly why do I use query select parameter is because I want to get value from `checkedListBox1` that already I defined before by using this code get all `checkedListBox1` value to determine select query.

```
string QueryParam = "cg.Chance_Number";//auto get chance_number as select mandatory

for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count; i++)
{
    QueryParam += ", " + ((clsItemList)checkedListBox1.CheckedItems[i]).Value;
}
```

Comment: You cannot pass a list of column names in a parameter like that.  You'd have to change the stored procedure to generate SQL from that then run it by using something like sp_executesql.

Comment: @juharrdo you have any suggest how to edit my stored procedure?

Comment: The term you're looking for is "dynamic SQL". Though be careful what you pass in so as not to open yourself up to SQL injection.

Comment: see if [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48914039/sql-server-cast-within-exec-dynamic-sql) helps. As @John points out - it's a double edged sword, so take care

Comment: @aminvincent, the stored procedure's SELECT must return the aliases the reader is waiting. Dynamic SELECT is useless.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use constructor with proper length for parameters as given below, to avoid the issue.[Read more on SQLParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter?view=netframework-4.8)

> public SqlParameter (string parameterName, System.Data.SqlDbType dbType, int size);

`cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("QueryParam", SqlDbType.NVarChar,1000)).Value = QueryParam;`

You need to make few more changes:

- The way you have defined the procedure is wrong. You have to define the procedure as dynamic sql for the @queryparam to get concatenated to the SELECT query as given below:

```
DECLARE @selectStmt NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @sqldefinition NVARCHAR(4000) = '@EventId nvarchar(255), @PeriodId nvarchar(255)'

SET @selectStmt += 'select distinct top 10000 ' + @QueryParam  +
'from ign..Chance_Generated cg
inner join ign..Contact c on cg.ContactID = c.ContactId
left join ign..CustomerAddress ca on ca.parentid = cg.contactid 
left join ign..new_cardlevelconfig cl on cl.new_cardlevelconfigid = c.new_cardlevel
left join ign..new_country co on co.new_countryid = c.new_country 
left join ign..new_province po on po.new_provinceId = c.new_Province
left join ign..StringMap sm on sm.AttributeValue = c.new_IDType
left join ign..new_city cy on cy.new_cityId = c.new_CityCounty
left join ign..new_transactionheader th on cg.New_Name COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = th.new_name COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
where cg.EventId= '''+ @EventId +''' and (ca.AddressNumber = ''1'' or ca.AddressNumber is null) and (sm.AttributeName is null or sm.AttributeName = ''new_idtype'') 
and cg.periodId = ''' + @PeriodId + ''';' 

EXEC @sp_executesql @selectStmt, @sqldefinition, @EventId , @PeriodId 
``

- Always refer the tables with proper schema in the query
```

ign.SchemaName.new_country
ign.SchemaName.new_province

Comment: if you don't mind, can you edit your answer to **ign** schema like my question code above?

Comment: how do i Handle thi error sir `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Procedure or function GetMembersDetailGenerateChanceTop10000 has too many arguments specified.` i implemented and run my program `SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()` indicated the error

Comment: The error itself explains what's the problem? You are passing more parameters than defined parameters in the stored proc. For `SELECT` you must specify the same number of parameters to stored procedure.

Comment: I think you are passing many sqlparameters as @iVad told.  you should have only three parameters added as `cmd.Parameters.Add( ... `

Comment: This should be concatenating the `@QueryParam` (or in this case the `@sqldefinition`) into the generated sql but it's just trying to pass in the column names as a parameter just like in the OP.

Comment: @juharr, Sorry. I got confused. Updated my answer.

Comment: Now the issue is that you concatenate the other stuff that is suppose to be parameters which will likely work if they are numbers, but not if they are strings.  Also you need to delimit the single quotes that are actually part of the query.

Comment: @juharr, you have got a visual compiler :) I have updated.